# Need first email value from list of emails in a field

Tags: formula-field

I have a field that captures a list of emails from a User like so:

john@test.com; mary@none.com; joe@abc.com

I'd like to capture the first email only in a separate formula field from this list (there may not be a semicolon if only one email is entered). Each email will always have a '.com' at the end. How can I grab only the first value?

Comment: is this a text field, text area field, or long text field?

Comment: Text field of 255 characters

Comment: so -- have you tried using the FIND and LEFT operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression in formula will work in the condition and data points provided in query,

```
LEFT(TextArea__c, FIND('.com', TextArea__c, 0)+3)
```

Comment: What about emails ending with anything than .com? Why not search for the delimiter instead?